# Solving cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 as cosine functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, nested-radicals

Common infinite nested square roots of 2 are well known from school grade.

We used to solve $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}$$ as
$x=\sqrt{2+x}$ which becomes $x^2 = x+2$ ==> $x^2-x-2=0$
The possible result is positive value which is $2$.

We also know similar negative infinite counterpart
$$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-...}}}$$ as $x=\sqrt{2-x}$ which becomes $x^2 = 2-x$ ==> $x^2+x-2=0$
The possible result is positive value which is $1$.

Even we can solve alternate signs of nested radicals like $$ \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+...}}}}$$ as $\sqrt5-1 \over 2$ and $$ \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-...}}}}$$ as $\sqrt5+1 \over 2$

> **Now the question is, is it possible to solve infinite nested square roots of of 'm' positive signs and 'n' negative signs in the infinite nested square roots of 2 in cyclic manner**

*Example 1* $$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+...}}}}}}$$
as **[- - +]** as infinite cycles

*Example 2*  $$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}}}}}}$$
as **[- - + +]** as infinite cycles.

> **To generalise the question how to solve** $$\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-...\text{m times} \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...\text{n times}}}}}$$ where $m, n \in {N}$

*Is there anyway to solve?*

Comment: +1 Goodness, what a beautiful question and answer, thank you for sharing it!

Answer (score 4):

**Solving cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2**

Half angle cosine formula offers easy solution to nested square roots of 2 as follows

$$2\cos\frac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{2+2\cos\theta }$$ and
$$2\sin\frac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{2-2\cos\theta }$$

Substitution of $x$ with $2\cos\theta$ in "infinite nested square roots of 2"

Simplest example is $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-...}}$ $--->$ in this infinite nested square roots of 2, $x = \sqrt{2-x}$ can be expressed as $2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2-2cos\theta}$ which can be simplified as $2\cos\theta = 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2} = 2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2})$
Now $\theta$ may be solved as $\frac{3\theta}{2}=\frac{π}{2}$ and $\theta$ = $\pi\over3$ which is 60°
Now the solution is obvious $2\cos60° = 1$

Checking for other simple nested square roots of 2 having alternate $'+'$ and $'-'$ signs as follows $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-...}}}}$$ this can be solved as follows by substituting $2\cos\theta$ for $x$
$2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-2cos\theta}}$ $==>$
$2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2+2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$
$2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{π}{2}-\frac{\theta}{2}})$$==>$
$2\cos\theta = 2\cos(\frac{π}{4}-\frac{\theta}{4})$
Now solving for$\theta$ as follows $\theta = (\frac{π}{4}-\frac{\theta}{4})$ ==>
$5\theta \over 4$ = $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and the result is $\theta = \frac{π}{5}$ which is $2\cos36° = \phi = \frac{\sqrt5 +1}{2}$ i.e. golden ratio which is also well known answer

> **Therefore substitution of $x$ with $2\cos\theta$ opens up a new way to solve infinite nested square roots of 2 which can be cyclic in nature**

Exploring further we can solve any combination of cyclic nested square roots of 2 as follows

If we remember some basic rules we can generalise the solving of these cyclic nested square roots of 2.
For the sake of simplicity further they are represented as **$cin\sqrt2$** (**c**yclic **i**nfinite **n**ested square roots of **2**)

$cin\sqrt2[1+1-]$ represents $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-...}}$
and
$cin\sqrt2[2-2+]$ represents $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}}$

By this method if we solve

$cin\sqrt2[1-2+]$ will be $2\cos\frac{2^2}{2^3+1}$ which is 2cos80°

$cin\sqrt2[1-3+]$ will be $2\cos\frac{2^3}{2^4+1}\pi$

$cin\sqrt2[1-4+]$ will be $2\cos\frac{2^4}{2^5+1}\pi$

$cin\sqrt2[1-5+]$ will be $2\cos\frac{2^5}{2^6+1}\pi$

Clearly it shows pattern as follows $$cin\sqrt2[1-n+]$$ will be represented in cosine terms as $2\cos(\frac{2^{n}\cdot\pi}{2^{n+1}+1})$

> **Next level of solution**
> $cin\sqrt2[2-1+]$ will be solved as follows

$$2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos\theta}}}$$
Subsequent steps as follows
$2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}}$
$2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2-2\sin\frac{\theta}{4}}$ $==>$
$2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}- \frac{\theta}{4}})$ $==>$ $2\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}- \frac{\theta}{8})$ $==>$ $2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}- \frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac{\theta}{8})$

Solving further for $\theta$ will result in $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{7}$

$\therefore$ $2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}$ can be expanded as $cin\sqrt2[2-1+]$

Solving $cin\sqrt2[2-2+]$ as follows

$2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos\theta}}}}$ $==>$ $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos\frac{\theta}{4}}}$ $==>$ $\sqrt{2-2\sin\frac{\theta}{8}}$ $==>$ $\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{8})}$ $==>$ $2\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{16})$ $==>$ $2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{16})$

Further solving for $\theta$ will lead to $\theta = \frac{4\pi}{15}$ which is 48°

Solving $cin\sqrt2[2-3+]$ as follows

$2\cos\theta = \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+2\cos\theta}}}}}$ $==>$ $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos\frac{\theta}{8}}}$ $==>$ $\sqrt{2-2\sin\frac{\theta}{16}}$ $==>$ $\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\theta}{16})}$ $==>$ $2\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{32})$ $==>$ $2\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{32})$

Further solving for $\theta$ will lead to $\theta = \frac{8\pi}{31}$ which is $\theta = \frac{2^3}{2^5-1}\pi$

$cin\sqrt2[2-4+]$ will be $2\cos\frac{2^4}{2^6-1}\pi$

$cin\sqrt2[2-5+]$ will be $2\cos\frac{2^5}{2^7-1}\pi$

$cin\sqrt2[2-6+]$ will be $2\cos\frac{2^6}{2^8-1}\pi$

We can observe the pattern and it is possible to generalise as follows

$$cin\sqrt2[2-n+] = 2\cos(\frac{2^n}{2^{n+2}-1})\pi$$

**Significance**

1. No need for solving cubic equation to get the value of $\cos10°$ - straight we can solve from $2\cos80°$(as $cin\sqrt2[1-2+]$ - first few digits can be calculated with 2 to 3 cycles of cyclic nested square roots of 2 (and with the help of half angle cosine formula we can easily calculate $2\cos10°$)
2. Of course as an alternative method to Taylor series expansion this method can be utilised to calculate the cosine values. (Taylor series expansion needs the value of $\pi$ to calculate the value of Trigonometric functions. Here we don't need)
3. Most interestingly Fermat numbers also included in representing the angles like $2\cos\frac{2}{5}\pi$, $2\cos\frac{8}{17}\pi$, $2\cos\frac{128}{257}\pi$, $2\cos\frac{32768}{65537}\pi$... can be represented as cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 as follows $cin\sqrt2[1-1+]$, $cin\sqrt2[1-3+]$,$cin\sqrt2[1-7+]$,$cin\sqrt2[1-15+]$... Respectively ( Deriving the values with python program will be effortless for the angles like $2\cos\frac{\pi}{65537}$ which otherwise look very much complicated

(The code below required very small fraction of a second to calculate $2\cos\frac{32768}{65537}\pi$)

*Python code for solving $2\cos\frac{32768}{65537}\pi$*
[image: Python code]
4. Conventionally we don't have exact representation of angles like $\cos\frac{\pi}{7}$, $\cos\frac{\pi}{11}$. But intuitively or with some effort these can be derived and represented as cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2.

> From above discussion, it is observable that any cyclic nested square roots of 2 can be solved to $2\cos\theta$ where $90° > \theta > 45°$ when the first sign is always negative $"-"$. By this method literally any positive integer angle can be represented as either finite nested radicals(like $2\cos45°$ as $\sqrt2$, $2\cos30°$ as $\sqrt3$ or $2\cos22.5°$ as finite nested radical $\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}$ or   cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 without requiring any imaginary numbers or Taylor series expansion as we saw in deriving $2\cos80°$ or $2\cos\frac{4π}{9}$ as $cin\sqrt2[1-2+]$

**Disclaimer: This is a part of my research on an attempt to solve interesting cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2**
**This is my partial answer for my question**

**I hope many of the people interested in nested radicals can reimagine the solving of various permutations and combinations of cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 in terms of cosine angles**