# Representing $\cos(\frac{π}{11})$ as cyclic infinite nested square roots of $2$

Tags: trigonometry, nested-radicals

**How can we represent $2\cos(\frac{\pi}{11})$ and $2\cos(\frac{\pi}{13})$ as cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2**

I have partially answered below for $2\cos(\frac{\pi}{11})$ which I derived it accidentally.

> Currently I have figured out for $q$ as denominator with patterns of $2^{n\pm1}$[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841604/solving-cyclic-infinite-nested-square-roots-of-2-as-cosine-functions)

**Is there any way to figure out pattern of nested radicals for other rational number $p \over q$ in $2\cos(\frac{p}{q})\pi$.**

**P.S.** I am able to figure out that the rational number $p \over q$ must be as follows $1\over4$ < $p\over q$ < $ 1 \over 2$ as $1<$ $\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2\pm...}}}$ $<2$

Answer (score 2):

Let $2\cos(\frac{\pi}{11})$ represented with the help of half angle cosine formula as follows

$2\cos(\frac{\pi}{11}) = \sqrt{2 + 2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{11})}=\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+ 2\cos(\frac{4\pi}{11})}}$

$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+ 2\cos(\frac{8\pi}{11})}}}$

Now $\frac{8\pi}{11}$ is more than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which makes $2\cos(\frac{8\pi}{11})$ to $-2\sin(\frac{5\pi}{22})$ and in turn this is $-2\cos(\frac{3\pi}{11})$

Next step plugging in leads to $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2- 2\cos(\frac{3\pi}{11})}}}$

Further expansion is $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+ 2\cos(\frac{6\pi}{11})}}}}$ and this is represented as $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2- 2\sin(\frac{\pi}{22})}}}}$ which is equal to
$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{5\pi}{11})}}}}$

**Final expansion is beautiful to observe**
$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{10\pi}{11})}}}}}$ which is equal to

$\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{11})}}}}}$

$\therefore 2\cos(\frac{\pi}{11}) = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{11})}}}}}$

> As these steps get repeated for ever we can conclude that
> $$2\cos(\frac{\pi}{11})$$ can be represented as cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 as follows and single cycle is
> $$\sqrt{2 +\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-}}}}}...$$ which repeats infinitely.
> This is represented simply as $$2\cos\frac{\pi}{11}=cin\sqrt2[2+3-]$$
> [Refer here for reverse way to derive cosine angle from cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2][1]

Comment: Very nice. But why do you have this as a separate answer to your own question? What was the purpose of this posting? If you want us to verify the solution, put it in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Currently I am not able find anywhere in the form of nested square roots for these kind of angles. (Except in wolfram alfa, where it presents in various other ways but not in a closed form like this). My approach is more basic as you observe and do not involve any radical with solution having imaginary component in solving the cos angles) Actually I did research on my own and I want to share to maths community. That is why I am putting in the Question and answer box. I always welcome suggestions, comments, critics to improve myself (:

Answer (score 1):

For your solution

$ 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)}}}}} $

I have add it (with your name) to Page 3 of my Notebook:

http://eslpower.org/Notebook.htm

I found the same result independently on July,2021.
Here is my method:

Since $(2^5+1) \bmod 33=0$, we have

$ 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{33}\right)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{33}\right)}}}}} $

and

$ 2 \cos \left(\frac{3\pi }{33}\right)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2 \cos \left(\frac{3\pi }{33}\right)}}}}} $

then we have

$ 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{11}\right)}}}}} $

For $ 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{13}\right) $, we may use the same method:

Since $(2^6+1) \bmod 13=0$, we have

$ 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{65}\right)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{65}\right)}}}}}} $

and

$ 2 \cos \left(\frac{5 \pi }{65}\right)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-2 \cos \left(\frac{5 \pi }{65}\right)}}}}}} $

then we have

$ 2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{13}\right)=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-2 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{13}\right)}}}}}} $

For more of my new results, I have post as my answers to your another question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232525/954936