# Interesting sequences when computing nested square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, trigonometry, nested-radicals

In my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841604/solving-cyclic-infinite-nested-square-roots-of-2-as-cosine-functions), I defined

$$f(\color{blue}{m},\color{red}{n})=
\sqrt{2\color{blue}{-}\sqrt{2\color{blue}{-}\cdots\color{blue}{-}
\sqrt{2\color{red}{+}\sqrt{2\color{red}{+}\cdots\color{red}{+}
\sqrt{2\color{blue}{-}\sqrt{2\color{blue}{-}\cdots\color{blue}{-}
\sqrt{2\color{red}{+}\sqrt{2\color{red}{+}\cdots\color{red}{+}
\sqrt{2\color{blue}{-}\cdots}}}}}}}}}$$
where there are $\color{blue}{m}$ consecutive "minus signs", followed by $\color{red}{n}$ consecutive "plus signs", and so on.

I will list some interesting values of $f(m,n)$ where $m = (n+1)$

$$
\begin{align}
f(1,0)&=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\\
f(2,1)&=2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)\\
f(3,2)&=2\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{11}\right)\\
f(4,3)&=2\cos\left(\frac{40\pi}{127}\right)\\
f(5,4)&=2\cos\left(\frac{176\pi}{513}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$

$f(n+1,n) = 2\cos(\frac{2^n\times2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{3\times2^{2n+1}+(-1)^n})\pi$

EDITOR's note: the OP will be responsible for fixing the rest of his post.

**Here is the beautiful part**

When $n = 0$

$$2\cos(\frac{2^n\times2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{3\times2^{2n+1}+(-1)^n})\pi = 2\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})$$

When $n = \infty$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2\cos(\frac{2^n\times2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{3\times2^{2n+1}+(-1)^n})\pi = 2\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})$$

**Therefore cosine angle for $n = 0$ and $n = \infty$ in solving above specific pattern of cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2, the result is same i.e. $2\cos\frac{\pi}{3}$**

> It is amazing to note that between $0$ and $\infty$ we get so many finite values of cosine angles solving cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 of above specific pattern.

**Question: Significance of such cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 ?**

Partially I got the answer for Numerator which forms specific number sequence as [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C12%2C40%2C176%2C672&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

In the denominator of radian value, it is 3,7,33,127,513,...
is the integer sequence, I'm not able to identify. Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the catch "interesting" tells me that they don't just want me to do their work, they want me to *want* to do their work. LOL. Probably, it would be wiser to explain their "cin" in a mathematically meaningful way, and hope somebody is interested in the problem without ridiculous propaganda.

Comment: Cyclic infinite nested square roots of 2 simply as $cin\sqrt2$. I have already explained in the link how to solve these $cin\sqrt2$. Difficult to get a better terminology. It will be very long post if I explain each and every thing in single post. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry for being blunt, but the main problem of this post (as of many others at this site) is: *why bother*? Even if *you* find that fascinating without any apparent reason, you might want to *try* to explain  to others *why*.

Comment: It's actually very interesting.... if you could present your work using concise mathematical notation. I will try to help you get started, in an *edit* I will make shortly. I won't have time to edit the whole thing, so please, try to get the idea, and continue. I'm sure the community will be interested in **well-presented**, curious, maths ideas.

Comment: There you go. 15 minutes of my time. I hope you will fix the rest, and also your previous post.

Comment: @BenjaminWang. Thanks a lot for edit. I had difficulty in notation as I'm in unrelated field.